# I want Fancybox to work on my divs - do I need to edit html?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox

I have some 'item' class divs, which are grey boxes with an image and a caption inside them. When they're clicked, I want them to appear bigger.

I have applied fancybox, but nothing happens. I have added all the relevant files into the html.

Here's the html code:

```
<div class="container">

<div class="item">
<img src="photo.jpg">
<p>Image caption</p>
</div>


<div class="item">
<img src="photo.jpg">
<p>Image caption</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="photo.jpg">
<p>Image caption</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
<img src="photo.jpg">
<p>Image caption</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. We ask that you show your code , include what you have tried and where you are going wrong. As your question stands right now , nobody can help because we can't see what you are doing or not doing, Also you may want to read the examples on [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: Start with something like this when you are posting so we can see what your code looks like: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXpJPw

Comment: Hey, I've added my code

Comment: I see html , no jQuery , I don't see where you are adding fancy box either. Are you getting any error messages in the console ?

Comment: Actually yes - 3 Uncaught syntax errors, and one uncaught type error. But the links at the far right hand side of the errors are all like error404.000webhost.com/

Comment: (that's the free web host I'm using)

Answer (score 1):

1. First Download and unzip your FancyBox Files
2. Second Use FTP (or not) to upload these files to your server
3. Third adjust paths of your FancyBox CSS and JS files to jive with the location of the folder of the root directory you uploaded the FancyBox Plugin to

For purposes of this demo I've used the same images from http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/.....

What many seem to have an issue with is not uploading the CSS & JS files but how to actually execute them.

---this is strictly basic, I just faced the same issue so I wanted to add some insight to this matter.

What is usually missing to make it execute is in the body section which are below the images that you're displaying as thumbs etc.-->this is some JS to make it work };-)

hint: it's in the source of the page that fancybox is downloaded from...

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#single_1").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          }`enter code here`
         });

       $("#single_2").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',

        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            }
        }
       });

       $("#single_3").fancybox({
        openEffect : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'outside'
            }
        }
       });

       $("#single_4").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'over'
            }
        }
       });
       });
       </script>
       <!--end above-->
       <!-- the above JS (in the body & under the images (i.e  
       below the anchor/image attributes...below the id of single_1 
       thru single_4 etc.)  
       executes & triggers the popup effect of the enlarged
       image...Below is similar to how your code should look 
       based on path adjustment within your server -->
       <!--end above-->


From Here you can hit the ground running and customize it as needed.

All the Code to make it Function right:


    <!--begin-->
    <!-- this format makes it work for you -->
    <!-- If you think not go here (below) -->
    <!-- http://www.kovacsphotography.com/fancyBox.html -->
    <!-- as said before adjust your paths to all JS & CSS -->
    <!--begin-->
        <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
    <title>|demo Of FancyBox |</title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-       latest.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancyBox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-  3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Add fancyBox -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.css"     type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancyBox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

    <!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/kovacsphotography/fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancyBox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
    </head> 

    <body> 



     <a id="single_1" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com                        /7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_b.jpg" title="Codirosso spazzacamino (Massimo Greco _Foligno)"> <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7367/16426879675_e32ac817a8_m.jpg" alt="" /> </a> 

    <a id="single_2" href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_b.jpg" title="Morning Twilight (Jose Hamra Images)"> <img src="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5612/15344856989_449794889d_m.jpg" alt="" /> </a> 

    <a id="single_3" href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7289/16207238089_0124105172_b.jpg" title="(Eric Goncalves (cathing up again!))"> <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7289/16207238089_0124105172_m.jpg" alt="" /> </a> 

    <a id="single_4" href="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8568/16388772452_f4d77a92c7_b.jpg" title="Arctic Paradise (Tom Draxler)"> <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8568/16388772452_f4d77a92c7_m.jpg" alt="" /> </a> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#single_1").fancybox({
              helpers: {
                  title : {
                      type : 'float'
                  }
              }
          });

        $("#single_2").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                }
            }
        });

        $("#single_3").fancybox({
            openEffect : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                }
            }
        });

        $("#single_4").fancybox({
            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
     </html>
```

The trick here is writing an executable JS for each image/anchor ID that you have (((or alternatively one executable JS file that functions for all your images etc.))) So if you have 9 different ones write a function to each corresponding ID in you anchored image placholder(s) within the body section of your document. AS long as your linked to your plugin files ((CSS & JS files)) you should be okay. You could host an image file from onedrive or dropbox if you wanted to...you just need to replace the path of the link where the file is to make it work..This seems spoon fed etc. but it might help others that come after..

Afterall it's just a guide to use some other persons code right? ;-)